# Write pyparsing rules for [NAME X-X-X] with synonyms

Tags: python, pyparsing

need help to write rules.

It is necessary to make a parser for the building adress in mask X-X-X.
Moreover, the names of buildings can be written in different ways.
For example synonyms are abbreviated or used.

```py
text = [
    "Building 1В-98-1У",
    "Building 1-4-13",
    "Build. 1-4-13",
    "1-4-13",
    "Line 1-4-13",
    "4-13",
    "Line 4-13",
    "Building 1А-02-1Б",
    "Building 1А-02/1Б",
    "1А-02/1Б",
    "Building 1Г-86",
    "1Г-86",
    "Building СТ6-19У",
    "СТ6-19У",
    "Building Line 6-19",
    "Building Line 6 prefix 19",
    "Lines 3",
    "L. 3",
]

INTEGER = Word(nums)
DELIMITER = Word("- /", max=1)
rus_alphas = 'йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбюЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ'

NAME = Word(alphas + rus_alphas + nums)


synonymsDefinitions = [
    ("Building", 'building'),
    ("Build", 'building'),
    ("Line", 'building'),
    ("l", 'building'),
]

SYNONYMS = pp.MatchFirst(makeLit(s, v) for s, v in synonymsDefinitions)


rule = ?????

for i in text:
    print(i, "->", BUILDING.parseString(i))
```